# Strange template syntax in <functional>

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std-function, stdbind

I have been looking at the source code for `std::function` and `std::bind` in gcc-4.7.2, and came across some syntax used for member function pointers which I don't understand.

What I don't understand is the specialisation of `_Maybe_wrap_member_pointer`:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Class>
struct _Maybe_wrap_member_pointer<_Tp _Class::*> // note no comma here
```

- Why is there no comma between `_Tp` and `_Class::*`?
- Given member function `void foo::bar()` (in my sample app below), what will `_Tp` and `_Class::*` resolve to here?

Below is my sample app which binds a member function pointer and object. (I have pulled out the source code relating to `std::bind` specialisations/internals for member functions)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
struct _Maybe_wrap_member_pointer;

template<typename _Tp, typename _Class>
struct _Maybe_wrap_member_pointer<_Tp _Class::*> // <-- I don't understand this
{                                                // why not <_Tp, _Class::*>  
    typedef std::_Mem_fn<_Tp _Class::*> type;    

    static type __do_wrap(_Tp _Class::* __pm)  
    {
        return type(__pm);
    }
};

template<typename _Func, typename... _BoundArgs>
struct _Bind_helper
{
    typedef _Maybe_wrap_member_pointer<typename std::decay<_Func>::type> __maybe_type;

    typedef typename __maybe_type::type __func_type;
    typedef std::_Bind<__func_type(typename std::decay<_BoundArgs>::type...)> type;
};

template<typename _Func, typename... _BoundArgs>
inline 
typename _Bind_helper<_Func, _BoundArgs...>::type
bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)
{
    typedef _Bind_helper<_Func, _BoundArgs...>   __helper_type;
    typedef typename __helper_type::__maybe_type __maybe_type;
    typedef typename __helper_type::type         __result_type;

    return __result_type(__maybe_type::__do_wrap(std::forward<_Func>(__f)),
                                                 std::forward<_BoundArgs>(__args)...);
}

struct foo
{
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;

    std::function<void()> fun = bind(&foo::bar, f);
    fun();

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed the syntax used to specify member pointer types as template parameters.

Suppose you have a class

```
struct Bar
{
  int n;
};
```

then a pointer to the member `Bar::n` would have to have its type declared as `int Bar::*`:

```
int Bar::* p = &Bar::n;
```

Note that `int` refers to the type the pointer points to, and `Bar::*` means "pointer to a member of `Bar`".

Now the function of your example,

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Class>
struct _Maybe_wrap_member_pointer<_Tp _Class::*> // note no comma here
```

accepts a template argument (just one!), which represents the member pointer type for a class `_Class`, pointing to non-static data member of type `_Tp`.

This is a *template specialization* of a class template that has *only one* template parameter:

```
template <typename T>
struct _Maybe_wrap_member_pointer
{ };
```

We can instantiate the specialization using the simple class above like this:

```
_Maybe_wrap_member_pointer<int Bar::*>
```

or using `decltype`:

```
_Maybe_wrap_member_pointer<decltype(&Bar::n)>
```

In both cases, `_Tp` is deduced to `int`, and `_Class` is deduced to `Bar`.

Comment: We might add that the data member type `_Tp` can be a class with an `operator()()` defined and therefore still be callable (despite not being a function). `bind` and `function` tries to take care of that.

Comment: `_Tp` can also be a function type, the `Tp Class::*` construct can refer to a pointer to member data _or_ pointer to member function

Answer (score 1):

> - Why is there no comma between _Tp and _Class::*?

jogojapan answered this part

> - Given member function void foo::bar() (in my sample app below), what will _Tp and _Class::* resolve to here?

A type such as `Tp Class::*` can represent a pointer to member data *or* a pointer to member function, in the latter case `Tp` will be a function type.

In your example `_Tp` will be the function type `void ()` and `_Class` will be `foo`